# Can't save "Many"-Entity of @OneToMany with Spring-Boot & Spring-JPA

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring Boot and MySQL. I followed [this](http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/) link for setting everything up and I'm able to connect to MySql and read/write data. But there is an 1:n-relationship and I'm not able to save entities of the many side:

```
    @Entity
    public class OneSideOfRelationship {
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
      private long oneId;
      private String someText;
      @OneToMany(mappedBy="oneId")
      private List<ManySideOfRelationship> manySide;

      [Constructor / Getter / Setter]
    }

    @Entity
    public class ManySideOfRelationship {
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
      private long manyId;
      @ManyToOne(targetEntity=OneSideOfRelationship.class)
      @JoinColumn
      private long oneId;
      private String someMoreText;

      [Constructor / Getter / Setter]
    }

    @Transactional
    public interface OneDao extends CrudRepository<OneSideOfRelationship, Long> {}

    @Transactional
    public interface ManyDao extends CrudRepository<ManySideOfRelationship, Long> {}
```

If I do this in my controller:

```
    [...]
    @Autowired
    @private ManySideOfRelationship manyDao;
    [...]
      ManySideOfRelationship many = new ManySideOfRelationship();
      many.setOneId(1L);
      many.setSomeMoreText("Text");
      manyDao.save(many);
    [...]
```

I got:

```
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not get a field value by reflection getter of com.package.database.OneSideOfRelationship.oneId; nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by reflection getter of com.package.database.OneSideOfRelationship.oneId
```

Out of my application.properties:

```
    spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://myurl:myport/mydatabase
    spring.datasource.username = myusername
    spring.datasource.password = mypassword
    spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
    spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

And something out of pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Hope somebody has an idea.

Comment: Your mappings are wrong, you are mapping a `long` where you should map the actual type. Looks like you are missing a little on how JPA mappings work.

Comment: Refer to Jens answer, and adding on top of it, you must mention explicitly in DAOImpl and this particular instance of Many is part of this One instance, usually achieved via getters/setters of association. Also, that's some naming convention you got there, my eyes still rollin... :D

Comment: Thank you very much. It's the thing that you build the database model and then you think to relational for java-coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `oneId` must be datatype of `OneSideOfRelationship` not long.

```
  @ManyToOne(targetEntity=OneSideOfRelationship.class)
  @JoinColumn
  private OneSideOfRelationship oneId;
```

Comment: and just to add thatyou have to save the OneSide before, and save the ManySide with the OneSide setted. Am i clear?